# External hard drive disappeared

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, diskutil, fsck

I’m currently suffering under my newly bought 6TB HDD.
I safely ejected it yesterday and when I plugged it in again, nothing happened. I then checked DiskUtility but was presented with a strange thing: [image: „Unformatiert“ reads as “unformatted”]
Since nearly everything important to me resides on this drive now, I don’t really know if I could recover from this loss.

I’m on 10.12.5, running on a MacBook Pro late ’13, if that’s even important.
Okay, I searched for a few things to do after that:

Output of `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            222.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                28.0 GB    disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +221.8 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 D1E19399-BC6F-4E9F-ADA5-D082A16EC2A3
                                 Unlocked Encrypted

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *6.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk2s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage MC-7                    6.0 TB     disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s3
```

Output of `diskutil cs list`:

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (2 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group E7AF9022-948A-415E-9B5E-F288DD70F8E5
|   =========================================================
|   Name:         Macintosh HD
|   Status:       Online
|   Size:         222140432384 B (222.1 GB)
|   Free Space:   0 B (0 B)
|   |
|   +-< Physical Volume 02D8A677-06DE-41ED-B936-DB70E2FE3656
|   |   ----------------------------------------------------
|   |   Index:    0
|   |   Disk:     disk0s2
|   |   Status:   Online
|   |   Size:     222140432384 B (222.1 GB)
|   |
|   +-> Logical Volume Family 5FFE6896-66C8-4E27-9B47-75900D365736
|       ----------------------------------------------------------
|       Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
|       Encryption Status:       Unlocked
|       Conversion Status:       Complete
|       High Level Queries:      Fully Secure
|       |                        Passphrase Required
|       |                        Accepts New Users
|       |                        Has Visible Users
|       |                        Has Volume Key
|       |
|       +-> Logical Volume D1E19399-BC6F-4E9F-ADA5-D082A16EC2A3
|           ---------------------------------------------------
|           Disk:                  disk1
|           Status:                Online
|           Size (Total):          221803835392 B (221.8 GB)
|           Revertible:            No
|           LV Name:               Macintosh HD
|           Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
|           Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 20344557-B1E9-4CEE-8472-28FA39379F4C
    =========================================================
    Name:         MC-7
    Status:       Offline
    Size:         0 B (0 B)
    Free Space:   -none-
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 4F2A854E-9B63-49EC-A47D-14FBD768C226
        ----------------------------------------------------
        Index:    0
        Disk:     disk2s2
        Status:   Checking
        Size:     6000726290432 B (6.0 TB)
```

Output of `diskutil repairdisk disk2`:

```
Started partition map repair on disk2
Checking prerequisites
Checking the partition list
Adjusting partition map to fit whole disk as required
Checking for an EFI system partition
Checking the EFI system partition's size
Checking the EFI system partition's file system
Checking the EFI system partition's folder content
Checking all HFS data partition loader spaces
Checking booter partitions
Checking booter partition disk2s3
Verifying file system
Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume
Checking extents overflow file
Checking catalog file
Checking multi-linked files
Checking catalog hierarchy
Checking extended attributes file
Checking volume bitmap
Checking volume information
The volume Boot OS X appears to be OK
File system check exit code is 0
Reviewing boot support loaders
Checking Core Storage Physical Volume partitions
Verifying storage system
Checking volume
disk2s2: Scan for Volume Headers
disk2s2: Scan for Disk Labels
Invalid Disk Label @ 4096: invalid field value
Invalid Disk Label @ 4198400: invalid field value
Logical Volume Group 20344557-B1E9-4CEE-8472-28FA39379F4C on 1 device
disk2s2: Scan for Metadata Volume
Logical Volume Group has a 24 MB Metadata Volume with double redundancy
Start scanning metadata for a valid checkpoint
Load and verify Segment Headers
Unable to bootstrap transaction group 5: cksum mismatch
Continue scanning metadata for an older checkpoint
Load and verify Segment Headers
Unable to bootstrap transaction group 4: cksum mismatch
No valid commit checkpoint found
The volume 20344557-B1E9-4CEE-8472-28FA39379F4C was found corrupt and needs to be repaired
Storage system check exit code is 1
Repairing storage system
Checking volume
disk2s2: Scan for Volume Headers
disk2s2: Scan for Disk Labels
Invalid Disk Label @ 4096: invalid field value
Invalid Disk Label @ 4198400: invalid field value
Logical Volume Group 20344557-B1E9-4CEE-8472-28FA39379F4C on 1 device
disk2s2: Scan for Metadata Volume
Logical Volume Group has a 24 MB Metadata Volume with double redundancy
Start scanning metadata for a valid checkpoint
Load and verify Segment Headers
Unable to bootstrap transaction group 5: cksum mismatch
Continue scanning metadata for an older checkpoint
Load and verify Segment Headers
Unable to bootstrap transaction group 4: cksum mismatch
No valid commit checkpoint found
The volume 20344557-B1E9-4CEE-8472-28FA39379F4C was found corrupt and can not be repaired
Storage system check exit code is 1
Repairing storage system
The volume disk2s2+disk0s2 cannot be repaired when it is in use
Checking volume
disk2s2: Scan for Volume Headers
disk0s2: Scan for Volume Headers
disk2s2: Scan for Disk Labels
Invalid Disk Label @ 4096: invalid field value
Invalid Disk Label @ 4198400: invalid field value
disk0s2: Scan for Disk Labels
Logical Volume Group E7AF9022-948A-415E-9B5E-F288DD70F8E5 on 1 device
Incomplete or inconsistent CoreStorage Physical Volume set
Storage system check exit code is 1
Problems were encountered during repair of the partition map
Error: -69716: Storage system verify or repair failed
Underlying error: 1: Operation not permitted
```

Output of `sudo gpt -r show disk2`:

```
      start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2           4         Pri GPT table
           6       76800      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
       76806  1465021067      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1465097873       32768      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1465130641           4         Sec GPT table
  1465130645           1         Sec GPT header
```

It says `Invalid Disk Label @ #: invalid field value`, that’s the first error I can spot. I tried `fsck_hfs` too, but got more or less the same results. 
I’m quite depressed atm, I don’t know what to do anymore...

**Edit**: The drive in question is indeed encrypted.

**Edit 2**: I was able to recover parts of a few important files (~1GB of a ~250GB) using a recovery tool (on particular “Data Rescue 4”) on a drive which had the files before I moved them.
I guess it’s worth a try when having such a problem, although you won’t get much results (but at least a few).
Thanks for the help though. I’m leaving the drive as-is in case someone should come up with a solution.

Comment: If this data is really that important to you I would recommend you consulting a professional data recovery service. They can at least duplicate all data of the drive that is still readable before you/they "mess" with the original while trying to fix it.

Comment: @klanomath: I edited the question.

Comment: @klanomath: I tried hfsexplorer and MacDrive, both didn’t even recognize the drive

Comment: @Kuro Something like this: [Recovering a non-readable disk on Mac OS X](https://nbalkota.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/recovering-a-non-readable-disk-on-mac-os-x/) > Comments > Shaheen
Feb 20, 2017 @ 16:37:39 & nbalkota's reply. **Don't** execute `diskutil cs createVolume ...`!

Comment: @klanomath I was on the exact same page yesterday. I’ve read the comment.

Comment: @Kuro Please execute `sudo dd if=/dev/disk2 of=/Users/<username>/Desktop/gpt.bin count=48 bs=512` (replace <username> by your short user name) and upload gpt.bin somewhere (pastebin/Dropbox/etc.)

Comment: @klanomath Here’s the file: https://n.biyori.moe/MdTpuJRT

Comment: @Kuro Now the 2nd one with `sudo dd if=/dev/disk2 of=/Users/<username>/Desktop/2ndgpt.bin skip=11721045128 count=40 bs=512`

Comment: @klanomath okay, here: https://n.biyori.moe/p26hCbbT

Comment: I guess I have to accept my misery. Maybe this is an opportunity for me to start over again, leaving quite a few digital memories behind. Fixing this issue is probably not even possible.

Comment: @Kuro If you enable root, install TeamViewer and [wxHexEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxhexeditor/), change to root and invite me to a TeamViewer session I may have a closer look to your problem.

Comment: @klanomath I’m not quite sure how to pm you since this site doesn’t even support that

Comment: @Kuro Please send any questions or credentials to klanomath(at)googlemail.com.

Comment: @klanomath I know it’s kinda late, but I sent you a message